# What is practical usage of CorrelationId and MessageId when sending telemetry?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, telemetry

In the Azure IOT Hub Client telemetry sample there are two calls you can make that are commented out:

```
 // Set Message property
 /*(void)IoTHubMessage_SetMessageId(message_handle, "MSG_ID");
   (void)IoTHubMessage_SetCorrelationId(message_handle, "CORE_ID");
 ...
 */
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/iothub_client/samples/iothub_ll_telemetry_sample/iothub_ll_telemetry_sample.c

I understand I can pass strings into these calls in a certain format.

But what is their use case in Azure?

What should go into these fields to best help the user process the telemetry in Azure IoT Hub?

This page tells me the format of message id, not much guidance:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct

Answer (score 1):

> IoT Hub is one of the first Azure services to support distributed tracing. As more Azure services support distributed tracing, you'll be able trace IoT messages throughout the Azure services involved in your solution.
>
> Enabling distributed tracing for IoT Hub gives you the ability to:
>
> Precisely monitor the flow of each message through IoT Hub using trace context. This trace context includes **correlation IDs** that allow you to correlate events from one component with events from another component. It can be applied for a subset or all IoT device messages using device twin.
>
> Automatically log the trace context to Azure Monitor diagnostic logs.
>           Measure and understand message flow and latency from devices to IoT Hub and routing endpoints.
>
> Start considering how you want to implement distributed tracing for the non-Azure services in your IoT solution.

[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-distributed-tracing) you can find more.